# Detectar ultimo archivo modificado en una carpeta PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código que sirve para leer el último archivo creado en un dorectorio con PHP. Funciona bien, pero lo que necesito es que pueda leer archivos solo de cierta extensión, por ejemplo archivos en .gif

Gracias y saludos.

```
<?php
function ultimo_modificado($dir='tu_directorio/', $type=0) {
    $ignore = array(
                '.',
                '..'
                );
    if(substr($dir, -1)!='/') {
        $dir .= '/';
    }
    if($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        $mas_nuevo = 0;
        $ultimo_nombre = false;
        while (false !== ($curfile = readdir($handle))) {
            if(in_array($curfile, $ignore)) continue;
            if(is_file($dir.$curfile) && $type==2) continue;
            if(is_dir($dir.$curfile) && $type==1) continue;
            if(filemtime($dir.$curfile)>$mas_nuevo) {
                $mas_nuevo = filemtime($dir.$curfile);
                $ultimo_nombre = $curfile;
            }
        }
        return $ultimo_nombre;
    }
    return false;
}
$ultimo_archivo = ultimo_modificado();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo probe rapidamente y parece que funciona

```
$files = glob("tu_directorio/*");
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filemtime", $files));
arsort($files);

$latest_file = key($files);

echo $latest_file;
```

Comment: Buena respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Dicen [por ahí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory) que [glob()](https://www.php.net/glob) funciona para ello

```
$files = glob('/path/to/dir/*.gif');
```

Luego sería iterar `$files` para encontrar el editado más recientemente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la restuestra Bro, pero como podría quedar mi código?? Soy muy novato en esto!! Me sería de gran ayuda

Comment: No creo que "Bro" sea la expresión más adecuada en este sitio. Un saludo.